# How to split custom resolution image to A3 resolutions in CorelDRAW X4?

Tags: draw, coreldraw

Good Evening,

I have one big problem. I created image with resolution 550mmx550mm in CorelDRAW X4. Now I need to split this image to several images with A3 resolution . How I can do it? If you don't understand, on image is for example beach. After split I want on one A3 image the upper left corner, on another one the upper right corner etc. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is this a programming question at all? If not, then StackOverflow is not the right forum to ask it. If yes, you need to explain better what you have already done to solve your problem and what it is that is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the node editing tool to crop the image.
[image: node editing tool, second from above.]

Even adding nodes is possible.
Afterward, use pull down menu 'bitmap' > 'crop' to finalize or leave it as is to be able to expand the image again.